# Finding most effective upper bound for TSP using MST

Tags: algorithm, graph, tree, minimum-spanning-tree, traveling-salesman

I'm curious as to what the most effective methods are to find the most optimal (or close to optimal) upper bound for the TSP using a MST.  I'm trying to optimize my algorithms for speed,  but I'm having trouble algorithmically computing "good" bounds after I find the MST.  I know a base bound would be `2 x MST length`, but this doesn't seem to be the best we can do.  Any references or insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably convert the MST into a tour, and that'll give you a bound less than 2 * MST length, in linear time. There is also an extension to MST, called Christofide's Algorithm that might be worth looking into as well.

Recommend taking a look at the Wikipedia page for [TSP heuristics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traveling_salesman_problem#Heuristic_and_approximation_algorithms).